# передать url изображения при клике на него в input text поле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста как передать url изображения в поле input text при клике на изображение

Comment: можите еще посмотреть эту сылку 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937162/jquery-get-the-image-src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="inputId" />
<img onclick="document.getElementById('inputId').value=this.src" id="imgId" src="...
```

---

```
$("#imgId").click(function() { $("#inputId").val(this.src); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать событие `click` на картинке. Чтобы получить значение атрибутов, можете метод jquery  attr или prop

```js
$("#my_image").on('click', function(e) {
  $("#my_input").val(e.target.src)
  console.log(e.target.src)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<img id="my_image" src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="click and move url to input" width=200 height=200/>
<input id="my_input" type="text"/>
</div>
```